# How to supress SignatureDeclareThrowsException warning for particular package in PMD?

Tags: pmd, static-code-analysis

We are using some third party framework which have one method which throws Exception. We can't change this behavior. PMD is giving me `SignatureDeclareThrowsException` warning for that code.

How can I configure PMD to ignore `SignatureDeclareThrowsException` warning in particular package ?
My class signature is like this

```
package my.company.ui.listeners;

public class XYZListner extends Composer<Component> {
    @Override
    public void onCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.onCompose(comp);
        // my code 
    }
}
```

I want to ignore above PMD warning in all class of `my.company.ui.listeners` package.

As per @HairyFotr suggestion, I modified strictexception.xml file and added following content in rule `SignatureDeclareThrowsException`.

```
    <properties>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//PackageDeclaration/Name[starts-with(@Image, 'my.company.ui.listeners')]" />
    </properties>
```

But still it is not ignoring these classes.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my answer? Please accept it or let me know if I can add something to it make it work for you.

Comment: @HairyFotr I have updated the question. And sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your ruleset you can exclude a specific path with the `exclude-pattern` tag.

`<exclude-pattern>.*/path/to/third/party/framework/.*</exclude-pattern>`

This will disable *all PMD warnings* for the specified path pattern, not just `SignatureDeclareThrowsException`, but since you can't change this code, I'm guessing you're not interested in any warnings from this package.

If you want to suppress only this warning, you can do so with `violationSuppressXPath` property where you include this rule in the ruleset. Find the rule and add the property inside it (change `third.party.framework` to the actual package name):

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException">
  <properties>
    <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//PackageDeclaration/Name[starts-with(@Image, 'third.party.framework')]" />
  </properties>
</rule>
```